# Issue retrieving Firebase data on React Native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the WeightGoal that's already been stored on my Firebase RealTime Database, but I'm getting the following error. "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {…})"

[image]

Here's my json file:

[image]

Here's my componentWillMount code:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/goals`)
    .on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({ WeightGoal: snap.val()})
    })
}
```

And here's how I'm referencing the value inside of render:

```
{this.state.WeightGoal}
```

My expectation is to see 170 displayed on the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap.val()` is the object consisting of the `goal` object in your database, because that is what you are referencing:

```
.ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/goals`)
```

So, if you want to store only the `WeightGoal property`, the line, where you use `this.setState` should look like this:

```
this.setState({ WeightGoal: snap.val().WeightGoal })
```

P.S. Next time try adding console.log(this.state) into render() to see what you are displaying. Or add a breakpoint in Chrome Debugger, which is a more reliable way.

Comment: Great answer Eduard. To reduce the amount of bandwidth used, I'd listen to ``.ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/goals/WeightGoal`)``, since that's all that is used.